# How to count all distinct rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table like below, how can I count and sum all distinct values?

```
student_name | section | score | class
-------------|---------|-------|-------
John         | B       | 32    | 8
Doe          | B       | 43    | 8
Jane         | A       | 33    | 8
Smith        | A       | 88    | 8
Pat          | B       | 99    | 9
```

The output I desire is following for each class. So for class `8` it would be:

```
section  |  num_records | score_total
---------|--------------|-------------
B        |   2          | 75
A        |   2          | 121
Total    |   4          | 196
```

Comment: GROUP BY, SUM, COUNT.

Comment: why last B with score 99 ignored from sum any logic

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin `So for class 8 it would be` Only class 8 is taken for calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(section, 'Total') AS section,
       COUNT(*) AS num_records,
       SUM(score) AS score_total
FROM t
WHERE class = 8
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (section, ())
ORDER BY section;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=586fbec8fe8f93bc36f1ce2eab59417c)**

Comment: This is great! Thanks. Would I use calesce similarly if I wanted `%` for each row as well?

Answer (score 0):

you could use union all and subquery

```
select section,count(*),sum(score)
from t
where class =8
group by section
union all
select 'Total',count(*),sum(score) from t
where class=8
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c1b89a08c3d2390cd512275e70cba928)
output

```
section     count   sum
 A           2      121
 B           2      75
Total        4      196
```